# Using Selenium Python generate a new password

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I forgot my password and I wrote this code with Selenium to try to recover my pass, but I don't know how to continue.
The button new password doesn't work.
Can someone help me? I try different ways to continue but I don't know. Is any way to enter?

I am trying to remember my password using the function. Something like force brute. So, I dont know how to make a loop generating a new password, with the function, enter it in the box "Contraseña: " until it is correct

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from playsound import playsound
import smtplib, ssl
from random import sample


def password_generator(longitud):
    abc_minusculas = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    abc_mayusculas = abc_minusculas.upper()

    numeros = "0123456789"

    secuencia = abc_minusculas + abc_mayusculas + numeros

    password_union = sample(secuencia, longitud)

    password_result = "".join(password_union)

    return password_result


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("http://siga.frba.utn.edu.ar/")
print(driver.title)

link = driver.find_element_by_id("page-try")
link.click()

time.sleep(1)

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu-page-try"]/p[4]/a')
link.click()

time.sleep(1)

search = driver.find_element_by_name("form_email")
search.send_keys("35335")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: You didn't forget your password... you are trying to generate passwords to unlock others' accounts. A normal person when they forget a password doesn't think... oh, I'll just create a random password generator to try all possible passwords. They go through passwords they might have used and then try the reset my password link (or contact HelpDesk) if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 The locator you used is not unique (there are two of them). So I replaced it with `xpath` locator `//input[@name='form_email']`.

2 You are using `time.sleep` everywhere. It may be slower then using Selenium's explicit/implicit wait and also it's very unstable
So, I added `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)` to your code and applied explicit waits.

3 Also, I noticed that `page-try` id is not unique, so I replaced it with `css` selector. If you are using find_element..., not find_elements... then your locators have to be unique.

**Solution**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib, ssl
from random import sample

PATH = '/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)

driver.get("http://siga.frba.utn.edu.ar/")
print(driver.title)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#page-try"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Usuarios registrados')]"))).click()
search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='form_email']")))
search.send_keys("35335")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

To click `Solicitar nueva contraseña` button use this xpath: `//a[contains(text(), 'Solicitar nueva contraseña')]`

Try using the locators I provided as examples for other elements on your site. Use this as a reference https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: Thanks! 
Anyway, I am trying to remember my password using the function. Something like force brute. So, I dont know how to make a loop generating a new password, with the function, enter it in the box "Contraseña: " until it is correct

Comment: Generating a new password is a different question. Your initial question was about unclickable button. If your initial question is solved, please accept the answer.

Comment: Ok. I will make another question. If you know the answer please help me

Comment: I suggest deleting password-generating code from this question and leave the code related only to locating elements. Paste updated code to a new question. And it will be related more to Python programming, then to Selenium.